# Select through pivot

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have three tables `products`, `features` and `product_features`.

**products**

```
id
name
...
```

**product_feature**

```
product_id
feature_id
```

**features**

```
id
name
...
```

My http request has a set of feature IDs Ex: `[3,6,14]`. How do I select a products that has all these features?

Comment: Please add some source code see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thank you got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT products.id FROM products
JOIN product_feature ON products.id = product_feature.product_id 
JOIN features ON product_feature.feature_id = features.id
WHERE features.id IN (3,6,14)
GROUP BY products.id HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```